# How to display record even if field is null in db table when click search

Tags: ms-access

I have main table that contain all data. if one of the field used in the combo is null then the record is not being displayed in the form.
but if i put any data in the fields that used in as combo.. then get record is displayed.

In my form, I have a combo for `empl_name` and `comp_name`, search & clear btn.

search btn in form is an embedded macro

```
[Emp_name] Like "*" & [Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo224] & "*" And
[comp_name] Like "*" & [Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo303]
```

for e.g if i select empl_name as 'tim' from combo box values.. when click search btn only the record 1 is displayed instead of the 3 records for tim.
since comp_name field in DB is null it dont display the other 2 null record

```
Data in table 'tbl_empl'
id| Empl_name | comp_name | type
1 | tim       | abcd      |  A
2 | tim       |           |  
3 | tim       |           |
```

How can do it to display the record even if some fields are null?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression

```
[Emp_name] Like "*" & [Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo224] & "*" And
(IsNull([comp_name]) OR Nz([comp_name]) Like "*" & [Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo303])
```

If the combo boxes are on the same form, you should be able to access them with `Me![Combo224]` instead of `[Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo224]`.

Comment: thxs! the above expression work fine.... but is there a way to put that in an event procedure-vba code? I'm adding more combo box and its getting limited error in the apply filter macro conditions. All 6 fields can be null. can search by emp_name, comp_name, status, type, category, sign.

Comment: See: [Access/VBA - Event handling Tutorial (Part 1) - First steps for beginners](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=access-vba-event-tutorial-beginner).

Comment: What you want to do it create a private vba sub that tests your combo boxes and other filter related controls for values or null and builds the filter as  a text string, then assigns it to the form and requeries. Then call that function for the after update event of each control that affects the filter.

Comment: writing it like that but getting error.. "compile error: Expected:line number or label or statement or end of statement"

Dim strSearchCriteria As Variant
strSearchCriteria = Null
strSearchCriteria = "NZ([emp_name],"") Like " * " & [Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo224] &"*'"
And NZ([comp_name],"") Like "*" & [Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo303] & "*"
And NZ([Status],"") Like "*" & [Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo311] & "*"
And NZ([type],"") Like "*" & [Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo317] & "*"
And NZ([sign],"") Like "*" & [Forms]![FrmTestSearch]![Combo319]) & "'"
end